# Manually skip a component from being created from the dfm

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to skip a component from being created from the dfm?

I have an visual component I sometimes do not want to be created. Of course I could create the component by hand, but this would be a lot of work since the component has a lot of items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually there **is** a way to accomplish this. Here is an example that skips a component of a specific class.

Add two event handlers to your form similar to these:

```
procedure TForm224.DoCreateComponent(Reader: TReader; ComponentClass: TComponentClass; var Component: TComponent);
begin
  if ComponentClass = <whatever component class shall be skipped> then begin
    Abort;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm224.DoReaderError(Reader: TReader; const Message: string; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Handled := True;
end;
```

Then override the form's `ReadState()` method this way:

```
procedure TForm224.ReadState(Reader: TReader);
begin
  Reader.OnError := DoReaderError;
  Reader.OnCreateComponent := DoCreateComponent;
  inherited;
  Reader.OnError := nil;
  Reader.OnCreateComponent := nil;
end;
```

If there are several instances of that component class and you need to check for an individual instance, you can use the `TReader.OnSetName` event:

```
procedure TForm224.ReadState(Reader: TReader);
begin
  ...
  Reader.OnSetName := DoSetName;
  inherited;
  Reader.OnSetName := nil;
  ...
end;

procedure TForm224.DoSetName(Reader: TReader; Component: TComponent; var Name: string);
begin
  if Name = <instance name> then begin
    Abort;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Downside is that this treats other reader errors as intent to skip the component. That can be avoided (in a rather clunky way) by creating an exception with a sentinel message which can be detected by the `OnError` event handler.

Comment: Another big downside is that it could not be applied to *individual* components. (`Component` is set to `nil`).

Comment: While this gets full points for being clever, it's the kind of thing that makes you want to kill the developer that decided to commit such a nasty turd into the repo.  There are better ways to manage components at runtime than this, surely.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, even in that case I would raise an EAbort exception with that message as that one is already ignored by the IDE.

Comment: @J.. This is needed from a workaround for a bug in a 3rd party component we can't solve for now. With this solution, we don't need to change or complete application structure, so I am happy with such a solution.

Comment: @UweRaabe, Note that in that case, the component is actually being **created** and then freed (and niled). although in the early stages of ti's creation, but it still being instantiated. So I guess a `FreeAndNil` in the Form Create could do (almost) the same job.

Comment: @kobik, there is still a slight difference: Although in the SetName event the component is already created, its properties are still not loaded from the DFM.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to skip a component from being created from the dfm?

There is no clean way to do this, in my opinion. I think you are looking for a method that can be applied using the form designer.

Uwe's answer shows a code based method that does indeed do what you ask, but I personally would regard it as too unwieldy for practical use. Furthermore Uwe's answer requires the optional component to be the only component of that class on the for. That is just not realistic.

In my view, the best options are either:

1. Have the component be created automatically as part of .dfm streaming, and then either destroy it or hide it at runtime.
2. Create the component optionally at runtime.

Comment: There is indeed a way as described in my answer.

Comment: @J... You are right, especially when taking kobik's point into consideration.